# Spark-shell Error object map is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to read json and parseout two values `valueStr1` and `valueStr2` from a Kafka topic `KafkaStreamTestTopic1` using spark streaming. And convert it to a data frame for further processing.

I am running the code in a spark-shell so spark context `sc` is available.

But when I run this script, it is giving me the following error:

> error: object map is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd
>            val dfa = rdd.map(record => {

Below is the script used:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, TaskContext}
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import play.api.libs.json._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("myApp").getOrCreate()
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

// Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
val topicsSet = Array("KafkaStreamTestTopic1").toSet

// Set kafka Parameters
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "group.id" -> "my_group",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> "false"
)

val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
  ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams)
)

val lines = stream.map(_.value)

lines.print()

case class MyObj(val one: JsValue)

lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  println("Debug Entered")

  import sparkSession.implicits._
  import sqlContext.implicits._


  val dfa = rdd.map(record => {

    implicit val myObjEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[MyObj]

    val json: JsValue = Json.parse(record)
    val value1 = (json \ "root" \ "child1" \ "child2" \ "valueStr1").getOrElse(null)
    val value2 = (json \ "root" \ "child1" \ "child2" \ "valueStr2").getOrElse(null)

    (new MyObj(value1), new MyObj(value2))

  }).toDF()

  dfa.show()
  println("Dfa Size is: " + dfa.count())


})

ssc.start()
```

Comment: have you tried renaming your `rdd` otherwise to avoid package clash ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is that `rdd` is also a package (`org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd`) that you imported automatically with the line:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
```

To avoid those kind of clashes, rename your variable to something else, for example `myRdd`:

```
lines.foreachRDD(myRdd => { /* ... */ })
```

Comment: I am now getting a new error now ` error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(MyObj, MyObj)]` at `}).toDF()`. Please help.

Comment: have you declared your case class outside the object with the main function ?

Comment: I don't have any main function. Just shell commands as shown in my above script. I have defined my case class as `case class MyObj(val one: JsValue)` before `lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {` statement in the given script above.

Comment: can you please give an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency of spark-streaming into your build manager

```
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % SparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % 
     "2.0.1"
```

You can use maven or SBT to add during build.

Comment: and I am not using any spark-mllib functions